# Fullscreen is not working on Iphone 6s and 5s

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, fullscreen

I got a problem with FullScreen mode on Iphone 6s and 5s - it does not work in Chrome and Safari about others i have no idea. I don not have any apple devices so i cannot even reproduce it by myself - it was reported by one of my customers. I already have installed Mac OS Siera on VMWare and tested my project with Safari - everything is fine. Now i am going to install XCode, but my Internet is weak so it will be very long process...
To work with FullScreen i use such stuff:

```
/** @namespace */
const THREEx        = THREEx        || {};
THREEx.FullScreen   = THREEx.FullScreen || {};

export default THREEx.FullScreen;

/**
 * test if it is possible to have fullscreen
 *
 * @returns {Boolean} true if fullscreen API is available, false otherwise
*/
THREEx.FullScreen.available = function()
{
    return this._hasWebkitFullScreen || this._hasMozFullScreen;
}

/**
 * test if fullscreen is currently activated
 *
 * @returns {Boolean} true if fullscreen is currently activated, false otherwise
*/
THREEx.FullScreen.activated = function()
{
    if( this._hasWebkitFullScreen ){
        return document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    }else if( this._hasMozFullScreen ){
        return document.mozFullScreen;
    }else{
        console.assert(false);
    }
}


THREEx.FullScreen.addEventListener = function(element, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', handler, false);
        element.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', handler, false);
        element.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', handler, false);
        element.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', handler, false);
    }
}

THREEx.FullScreen.removeEventListener = function(element, handler) {
    if (element.removeEventListener) {
        element.removeEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', handler, false);
        element.removeEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', handler, false);
        element.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', handler, false);
        element.removeEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', handler, false);
    }
}


function exitHandler()
{
    if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement !== null)
    {
        /* Run code on exit */
    }
}

/**
 * Request fullscreen on a given element
 * @param {DomElement} element to make fullscreen. optional. default to document.body
*/
THREEx.FullScreen.request   = function(element)
{
    element = element   || document.body;
    if( this._hasWebkitFullScreen ){
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }else if( this._hasMozFullScreen ){
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }else{
        console.assert(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Cancel fullscreen
*/
THREEx.FullScreen.cancel    = function()
{
    if( this._hasWebkitFullScreen ){
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }else if( this._hasMozFullScreen ){
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }else{
        console.assert(false);
    }
}

THREEx.FullScreen._hasWebkitFullScreen  = 'webkitCancelFullScreen' in document  ? true : false;
THREEx.FullScreen._hasMozFullScreen = 'mozCancelFullScreen' in document ? true : false;
```

The most confusing thing is that it is working well with my device Huawei Honor 6 (Android 4.4.2, Chrome and Firefox) and Chrome dev tools emulation. So where is the problem? iOS? Why is it working with Android Chrome and it is not with iOS Chrome?

If anyone would like to see all the project or has iPhone and can test it - go to http://3dflipbook.net, there are jQuery or WordPress plugin demos. I will be pleasant for any details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have reproduced the issue in Safari with XCode iPhone 6S Simulator, so the problem is really exists.

Answer (score 1):

It seems i found an answer on my question: iOS Safari does not support FullScreen API http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen. iOS Chrome is more iOS Safari than Chrome itself http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/chrome-ios-android-4-1-jelly-bean-html5.